Why every time I install a package in termux using npm an error log always appears and I don't know what to do?

error code EACCES
npm error syscall symlink
npm error path ../semver/bin/semver.js
npm error dest /storage/emulated/0/projek/node_modules/.bin/semver
npm error errno -13
npm error Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../semver/bin/semver.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/projek/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm error     at async symlink (node:internal/fs/promises:1001:10)
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm error     at async #createBinLinks (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:394:5)
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm error     at async #linkAllBins (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:375:5)
npm error     at async #build (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:160:7)
npm error     at async Arborist.rebuild (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:62:5)
npm error     at async [reifyPackages] (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:325:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:142:5) {
npm error   errno: -13,
npm error   code: 'EACCES',
npm error   syscall: 'symlink',
npm error   path: '../semver/bin/semver.js',
npm error   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/projek/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2024-10-27T09_47_42_129Z-debug-0.log

This error log always appears when I install a package in termux using npm
That it always appears when I want to install a package using npm, but when I install it in the main directory, it can be installed but if I install it in a folder it always appears error message like that, maybe this is a small problem for seniors, because I am a beginner so I am confused about what to do
